# trying to make the switch to pdo, random image script doesn't always fire

Tags: php, mysql, random, pdo

I'm trying to make the switch over to PDO. Though I've quickly ran into a few problems, one that I haven't been able to solve is with my random image script. I have a previous post about this not working, it had to do with the `SELECT MAX(id) needed to be SELECT MAX(id-6)`. The problem before was that I was getting a random number of random images, never 6.

Now the problem is that sometimes I get the six random images, sometimes I get none. I am hoping that someone could look at my script to see if they can spot any problem with it.

Thanks sometimes a second pair of eyes is all it takes:

```
<?php
$passed_cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat']);
$passed_sub_cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sub_cat']);

include ('../../connection.php');

$related_images = "SELECT *,r1.id as main_id 
                   FROM images AS r1 
                   JOIN 
                   (
                        SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id-6) 
                                               FROM images)) AS id
                    ) AS r2 
                    WHERE r1.id >= r2.id 
                        AND public_approved='Approved'
                        AND category = :category
                        AND sub_category = :sub_category
                    ORDER BY r1.id ASC 
                        LIMIT 6
                            OFFSET 20";

$q = $conn->prepare($related_images);
$q->execute(array(
':category' => $passed_cat,
':sub_category' => $passed_sub_cat));


if(!$q)
{
    die("Query failed due to: ". $conn->errorInfo());
}

$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

while($row = $q->fetch())
{
echo "<div style='float:left; margin:2px;' >";
echo '<a href="sub_page.php?cat='. $passed_cat .'&sub_cat='. $passed_sub_cat .'&id='. $row['main_id'] .'"><img src="../../files/small/thumb0_'. $row['item_name'] . '.' . $row['file_extension'] . '" style="width:96px;" border="0"></a>';
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

EDIT: Connection.php

```
<?php

    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "all_sites";
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$db_username,$db_password);
}
catch (PDOException $pe)
{
    die('Connection error, due to: ' .$pe->GetMessage());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_real_escape_string() is not required and could possible cause problems if your not using the mysql_connect()

[From the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) `mysql_real_escape_string('',*link_identifier)`

> - The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the
>     last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is
>     found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with
>     no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING
>     level error is generated.

Just pass your $_GET vars to the execute array:

```
$q->execute(array(':category'=>$_GET['cat'], ':sub_category'=>$_GET['sub_cat']));
```

Comment: tried and tested what you are saying here, however the error still remains

Comment: have you checked your query in phpmyadmin and it always works, also not related but change localhost to 127.0.0.1, it will speed up PDO

Comment: thanks for the tip, when in phpmyadmin it does not always work. Sometimes it is returning an empty set, I'll try starting over to see if I can get it to work. Thanks